# How to open lead drum trap under sink?

Tags: plumbing, sink

The sink at my workplace clogged so I looked to open up the trap and clear it out. The trap looks like a drum trap, maybe installed upside down as it has the lid on the bottom.
I went to open it with some channellock pliers and they bit into the metal, so I'm not sure if it is lead as the metal is very soft. I couldn't turn it without shredding the head.
I'll bring some WD-40, tomorrow to try and let it loosen up.

Questions, is there any special considerations to opening this if it is lead?
Any tips on how to get it to open without shredding it besides a penetrating oil?
Can I replace the lid with a PVC lid into this fixture?

Images attached.[image]

Comment: In most locations, the intersection of "at my workplace" (thus, a commercial environment) and "plumbing" means work should be having a plumber deal with it. Local rules may vary somewhat, but the odds that this is properly or legally your job are low.

Comment: If the metal feels "soft" like this, it's a dead giveaway that it is indeed lead. (The dull dark grey colour is also typical.) Lead has one of the lowest yield strengths of all the metals you can come across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like it's installed correctly. No problem opening it if it's lead unless you eat the shavings. Those are usually opened up with a box end wrench or a pipe wrench. As you found out, Channel locks pliers just don't work. Depending on how bad you shredded the bolt top, You might have to get a large pipe wrench and grab around the outer lip of the plug. You should have someone support the trap while you're doing this so you don't damage the lead seals where the pipe goes into the wall. It's a toss up on whether or not a PVC plug will fit.

Comment: I would think that a 1mm smaller box wrench might work if the bolt is messed up. Hammering it into the soft lead may reshape it to fit the tool. I'd suggest a 6-sided wrench, not a 12-sided.